# footcite not getting displayed

Tags: beamer, biblatex

I have used the package

```
\usepackage[style=mla,babel=hyphen,backend=biber]{biblatex}
```

This is my `ref.bib` file

```
@BOOK{HK,
AUTHOR={H. Kopka and P. W. Daly},
TITLE={A Guide to LaTeX},
PUBLISHER={Addison-Wesley},
ADDRESS={Reading, MA},
YEAR=1999.
}

@misc{git1,
author = {Robert Kingston},
title = {A simple javascript multivariate testing framework},
year = {2013},
publisher = {GitHub},
journal = {GitHub repository},
howpublished = {\url{https://github.com/jamesyu/cohorts}},
commit = {5d0f2cc8aa769ddb407869faac1ecf268677c6b9}
}
```

This is my frame

```
\begin{frame}[fragile]{Implementation of Multivariate Testing}
\begin{itemize}
\item Need to specify variation of elements on a Page \footcite{git1} 
\begin{minted}{javascript}
Cohorts.Options.debug = true;
font_test = new Cohorts.Test({
    name: 'hello-goodbye',scope: 1,//Set the scope
    sample: 1, cohorts: { hello: {
            onChosen: function() {
                $('p.message').html('Register');}},
        goodbye: {
            onChosen: function() {
                $('p.message').html('Submit');}},},

\end{minted}
\item All results can be accessed from the Google Analytics dashboard
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

In the `\footcite` only the number is getting displayed that is 2

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2):

First a remark:  please change in your first bib entry `YEAR=1999.` to `YEAR=1999,` (change dot to comma).

With a little testing with other styles instead of your used `mla` makes clear, that the style `mla` is the problem.

If you change the `biblatex` style to for example `style=authoryear-comp,` everything works well and your footcite is well shown.

**Conclusion:**

The style `biblatex-mla` is faulty.  I suggest not to use it (or ask the maintainer to correct it). Because I do not know this style (and do not want to invest time to study it) I can't tell you an alternative style.  Please check the documentation.

Please try the following MWE (and play with both styles, comment and uncomment):

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{HK,
  AUTHOR    = {H. Kopka and P. W. Daly},
  TITLE     = {A Guide to LaTeX},
  PUBLISHER = {Addison-Wesley},
  ADDRESS   = {Reading, MA},
  YEAR      = 1999,
}

@misc{git1,
  author    = {Robert Kingston},
  title     = {A simple javascript multivariate testing framework},
  year      = {2013},
  publisher = {GitHub},
  journal   = {GitHub repository},
  commit    = {5d0f2cc8aa769ddb407869faac1ecf268677c6b9},
  howpublished = {\url{https://github.com/jamesyu/cohorts}},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[%
  style=authoryear-comp,
% style=mla,
  autolang=hyphen,
  backend=biber
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

%\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]{Implementation of Multivariate Testing}
\begin{itemize}
\item Need to specify variation of elements on a Page\footcite{git1} 
\item All results can be accessed from the Google Analytics dashboard
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \textcite{knuth:ct:e} \cite{git1} \textcite{git1}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Bibliography}
  \printbibliography
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

with the result:

[image]

Comment: The last update to `biblatex-mla` was in May 2013, and since then `biblatex` has progressed a bit, so there are bound to be some rough edges. (But `biblatex-mla` states to be compatible with version 2.5, so many things will work OK.) For first citations in footnotes `biblatex-mla` calls the driver `footcite:<entrytype>`. Unfortunately, it does not define a driver `footcite:misc`, so we get no output with `git1`. Other types like `@book` do work.