# biblatex Error 'cite' undefined: autocite=footnote with biblatex-mla

Tags: biblatex, errors, footnotes, citing, mla-style

I would like to use the *MLA citation style in footenotes*. The following mwe produces the expected result.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}    
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=mla]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{thesis.bib}

\begin{document}
  foo\footcite{gof}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, instead of the `\footcite` command I would like to use the `\autocite` command. So, I change the code as follows.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=mla, autocite=footnote]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{thesis.bib}

\begin{document}
  foo\autocite{gof}
\end{document}
```

But, this does not compile. I am getting the error:

> `! Package biblatex Error: Bibliography macro 'cite' undefined.`

How can I fix this error and use the MLA-style with `autocite=footnote`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go with

```
\DeclareAutoCiteCommand{footnote}{\footcite}{\footcites}
```

to let `biblatex-mla` know what to do with `autocite=footnote`.

MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}    
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=mla, autocite=footnote]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareAutoCiteCommand{footnote}{\footcite}{\footcites}

\begin{document}
  foo \autocite{sigfridsson} and\footnote{foo\autocite{sigfridsson}}
\end{document}
```

Keep in mind that `biblatex-mla` has not been update for quite some time and a number of internals have changed since the last update, so there are bound to be some problems. See for example [URL in footcite mla](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/276755/35864). It might be worth thinking about doing a switch, but if everything else works for you, don't rush things.